# 2 observers - How does the system decide which runs first

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

If you have 2 extensions each with an observer on newsletter_subscriber_save_after how does the system decide which extension runs first?

Comment: If my memory serves me right - alphabetically

Comment: This really good post from Alan Storm will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934553/how-do-you-set-the-sort-order-for-event-observers-in-magento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observers are registered and therefore also executed in the order the corresponding extensions are loaded. You can read more about the load order in the [blog post by Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_declared_modules_tutorial). Just a short hint: You can force that your module A is loaded before another module B by placing a `depends` tag into your `app/etc/modules/Namespace1_ModuleA.xml`:

```
<depends>
    <Namespace2_ModuleB/>
</depends>
```